# Dynamic context menu in Google Chrome. Runtime error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, runtime-error, contextmenu

The code given below works fine for 2 selections but crashes on subsequent selections.

Content.js -

```
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', function(event){
            var selected = window.getSelection().toString().trim();
            chrome.extension.sendMessage({
                   'message': 'updateContextMenu', 
                   'selection': selected});
}, true);
```

BackgroundScript.js -

```
function SelectionType(str) {
  if (str.match("^[0-9]+$"))
      return "number";
  else if (str.match("^[a-z]+$"))
      return "string";
  else
      return "other";
}
var optionOne = {'enabled': true, 
        'title': "Some Title One '%s'", 
        "contexts": ["selection"],
        'onclick': functionOne
        };
var optionTwo = {'enabled': true, 
        'title': "Some Title Two '%s'", 
        "contexts": ["selection"],
        'onclick': functionTwo
        };
var cmid = null;
// a message listener that will modify the context menu
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message == 'updateContextMenu') {
        if (request.selection !='') {
          var type = SelectionType(request.selection);
          if (type == "number") 
                if(cmid != null) {
                    chrome.contextMenus.update(cmid, optionOne); 
                }
                else {
                    cmid = chrome.contextMenus.create(optionOne);
                }
          else if (type == "string")
                if (cmid != null) {
                    chrome.contextMenus.update(cmid, optionTwo);
                }
                else {
                    cmid = chrome.contextMenus.create(optionTwo);   
                }
        } else if (cmid != null) {
            chrome.contextMenus.remove(cmid);
            cmid = null;
        }
    } else {
        sendResponse({});
    }
});
function functionOne(info, tab) {
    console.log("Function One");

    chrome.tabs.create({ 
        url: "some url" + info.selectionText,
    })
}

function functionTwo(info, tab) {
    console.log("Function Two");

    chrome.tabs.create({ 
        url: "some url" + info.selectionText,
    })  
}
```

Getting the following error while creating context menu. I don't have much clue why is it crashing.

> Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property 'generatedId': Unexpected property.
>       at chrome-extension://acpffpbkehpfofhgilcophibgbkhmmba/script.js:46:42handler @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8exports.handle @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:100EventImpl.dispatch_ @ extensions::event_bindings:384EventImpl.dispatch @ extensions::event_bindings:401target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19publicClass.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:94messageListener @ extensions::messaging:188target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19EventImpl.dispatchToListener @ extensions::event_bindings:395target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19publicClass.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:94EventImpl.dispatch_ @ extensions::event_bindings:379EventImpl.dispatch @ extensions::event_bindings:401target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19publicClass.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:94dispatchOnMessage @ extensions::messaging:316

Comment: Does anything change if you use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage` instead? `extension` variants are deprecated.

Comment: Nope, problem persists...the code crashes on `chrome.contextMenus.create` statement.

Comment: Do not re-use `optionOne` and `optionTwo`. The implementation of chrome.contextMenus modifies the object in a way that is incompatible with the scheme definition, and that causes an error.